# Scoping in for loop with if statement- pandas.append does not work in loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, scope

The piece of code returns 10, which is what I would expect

```
for i in range(5):
    if i == 0:
        output = i
    else:
        output += i
print(output)
```

Why does this code only return the dataframe created in the if section of the statement (i.e. when i ==0)?

```
for i in range(5):    
    if i == 0:
        output = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2))
    else:
        output.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2))
print('final', output)
```

The above is the MVCE of an issue I am having with this below code:

**More context if interested:**

```
for index, row in per_dmd_df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        output = pd.DataFrame(dmd_flow(row.balance, dt.date(2018,1,31),12,.05,0,.03,'monthly'))
    else:
        output.append(pd.DataFrame(dmd_flow(row.balance, dt.date(2018,1,31),12,.05,0,.03,'monthly')))
print(output)
```

Where I have an input DataFrame with one row per product with balances, rates, etc.  I want to the data in each DF row to call the dmd_flow function (returns a generator that when called within pd.Dataframe() returns a 12 month forward-looking balance forecast) to forecast changes in the balance of each product based on the parameters in the dmd_flow function. I would then add all of the changes to come up with the net changes in balance (done using group by on the date and summing balances).

Each call to this creates thew new DataFrame as I need:

```
pd.DataFrame(dmd_flow(row.balance, dt.date(2018,1,31),12,.05,0,.03,'monthly'))
```

but the append doesn't work to expande the output DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, (unlike `list.append`) [`DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is not an in-place operation. See the docs for more information. You're supposed to assign the result back:

```
df = df.append(...)
```

Although, in this case, I'd advice using something like `apply` if you are unable to vectorize your function:

```
df['balance'].apply(
     dmd_flow, args=(dt.date(2018,1,31), 12, .05, 0, .03, 'monthly')
)
```

Which hides the loop, so you don't need to worry about the index. Make sure your function is written in such a way so as to support scalar arguments.

Comment: @coldspeed, thanks for that! I did not realize that it was not in place, since the docs show a.append(b), and no mention of in place in the Dataframe.append page.  I'll take a look at how to vectorize a function.  I'm unclear what that means here.

Comment: @ivan7707 The doc also mentions the return value: `Returns: 
appended : DataFrame`. A vectorised function is one that can operate on the entire series/column instead of one value at a time. If you don't know what it is, don't worry about it for now.

Comment: @coldspeed,  ha, I thought that meant it appended it to the original DF in place.  Thanks for the clarification.  Sounds like vectorizing is like set based queries in SQL vs cursor.